# Updating an existing Object fails with error INVALID_FIELD_FOR_INSERT_UPDATE

Tags: master-detail, update, upsert, smartsync

This is the exact error : from smartSync SFLogger

> ERROR com.salesforce : Sync type:syncUp id:6 FAILED cause:Server call for sync up failed error:Error Domain=CSFNetworkErrorDomain Code=400 "Unable to create/update fields: XXXX_C__c. Please check the security settings of this field and verify that it is read/write for your profile or permission set." UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=INVALID_FIELD_FOR_INSERT_UPDATE, isAuthenticationFailure=false, NSLocalizedDescription=Unable to create/update fields: XXXX_C__c. Please check the security settings of this field and verify that it is read/write for your profile or permission set., action=*}

Actually what I am trying to do :

I have SObject `ClassA__c` which is a parent 
I have another SObject `ClassB__c` which has field `ClassA__c_ID` as `Master-Detail(ClassA__c)`

Now when I create an object of type `ClassB__c`, it works fine , can create and sync its added and synced to salesForce

Now when I update some other independent field `(Docket__c ,    Number(10, 0))` in the `ClassB__c` object and try to upsert and Sync using smartSync . It fails with that error mentioned above.

I believe it's happening because we have Master-Detail field in `ClassB__c` 
cause I have already verified, we have all the write/read access with the profile. 
How can we exclude Master-Detail field only while an update through smartSync but include while we create the new object.

Answer (score 0):

[Example Gist of Custom Sync Up target](https://gist.github.com/frontendloader/fb7673e6723c900f6de3a81162861f38)

I've experienced the same thing, and had to [write a custom SyncUp target](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mobile_sdk.meta/mobile_sdk/entity_framework_native_up_target_def.htm) to resolve this issue. You extend the base SyncUp target, and then override whatever methods you need to override.

I only have experience with iOS, so I overrode this method:

```
- (void)updateOnServer:(NSString*)objectType
          objectId:(NSString*)objectId
            fields:(NSDictionary*)fields
   completionBlock:(SFSyncUpTargetCompleteBlock)completionBlock
         failBlock:(SFSyncUpTargetErrorBlock)failBlock
```

The `fields` argument is a dictionary that determines what value to set on what field when updating. The `objectType` argument is the metadata name (Account, OpportunityLineItem etc...) of the `sObject` that is currently being operated on.

When you override this method, check `objectType` to see if it is your `sObject` that has a Master/Detail relationship. If it is, make a new `NSDictionary` of `fields` and exclude the Master/Detail field that cannot change. Then you can call `super updateOnServer` with the new field argument so that the standard behavior resumes without the Master/Detail field present.

From there, you'll need to use [syncUpWithTarget](https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-iOS/blob/master/libs/SmartSync/SmartSync/Classes/Manager/SFSmartSyncSyncManager.m#L417) rather than plain `syncUp` to specify that your custom SyncUp target should be utilized.